# Activities hot-corner in 19.10

Tags: unity-dash, 19.10

I updated fron 19.04 to 19.10 this morning. The first issue I have found is that several of my Gnome extensions have stopped working due to an issue with the activities hot-corner. The main problem is that Dash-to-Dock no longer works and a re-install results in error. Several other extensions result in a warning about conflict with the activities hot corner. I have tried to turn off the hot corner in Gnome-Tweaks but clicking the switch on or off makes no difference. I also tried installing the "No hot corner" extension but that resulted in an error too.

I would like to continue using Ubuntu 19.10 as I have been doing with earlier versions, with a Dash-to-Dock appearing at the bottom of the screen when I move my mouse there. Does anyone know how I can achieve that?

Comment: OK I will edit the question.

Comment: @DK Bose I appreciate that but mentioning Wayland puts many users off answering. And I have now checked and the same problem appears under X11 anyway. I think I will always check that Wayland is not the problem before posting in future. I eanted to post a screenshot of the warning but screenshot is not saving screenshots at the moment :-( As soon as I can get a screenshot I will add it to the question.

Comment: Remove all extensions that you installed yourself, then use dconf-editor to configure the dash-to-dock settings, which actually are the ones are used by the Ubuntu dock (which is based on Dash to Dock).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct version of Dash to Dock installed, i.e., the version for Gnome Shell 3.34, which is the one used in Ubuntu 19.10.

You may then configure the dock using the configuration dialogs of Dash to Dock. Eventually, you can afterwards remove Dash to Dock and enable the Ubuntu Dock extension: the Ubuntu Dock extension, which is based on Dash to Dock, uses the same settings and will behave the same.

The plethora of options available in Dash to Dock are all available to Ubuntu Dock as well. Only, Ubuntu Dock does not expose these options to the user. Thus, alternatively, you can configure Ubuntu Dock directly using `dconf-editor` (not installed by default), This approach eliminates the need to install extra extensions.

Comment: Thanks, I configured Ubuntu Dock 'using dconf-editor'. Now everything is as I like it except with Dash-to-Dock I could have the doch in the middle of the screen at the bottom but with Ubuntu Dock it spreads across the whole screen even if the icons stop in the middle.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer but it doesn't answer the main question of how to disable the Avtivities Hot Corner in 19.10. There are other Gnome extensions affected. Plus I don't want iton my topbar-

Comment: The answer is: using Tweak Tool, at least in normal circumstances. You will have to check your extensions first. Disable them all, except those that are installed systemwide by default (e.g. Ubuntu Dock). See whether (after restarting GS) you can activate/disable hotcorners. Then add extensions one by one back in to see when the issues reappear. For what you want, you do not need any extra extension.

Comment: OK. Your answer is accepted as the solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Dash-to-panel version 23, has the habit of re-enabling "Activities Hot Corner". Any solution?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli filing an issue with the developers of Dash-to-panel would be an obvious first action. Otherwise, feel free to post a well documented question on this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Dash to dock does work but you need the correct version for 19.10. That said the [dash to panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) extension many users find it much better. Here is the second comment on the link:

> God heavens where have you been hiding? Only found you 'cos Ubuntu
>   19.10 killed dash-to-dock. Dash to Panel excellent, stable and an all-round better implementation. Thanks very much.

The dock is moved to the top with the indicators and not to the bottom as you were seeking.

Comment: Dash to Dock for sure *does* work in 19.10 provided the correct extension version is installed. Please correct in your answer.

Comment: @vanadium Thank you for clarifying. I left the user's comment in the answer to show the myths out there.

Answer (score 0):

It happened the same to me when upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10 with both extensions (dash to dock and dash to panel).

Open the browser and go to  and the installed apps tab. Install the gnome extension for your browser if you don't have it.

You'll see that both extension are marked with the error flag. Update both extension using the green button with the arrow. After updating you'll see that the error flag stands.

Press Alt-F2 and then "r" (without the quotes). Gnome will reload the interface and extensions. After reloading it should work. It worked for me.